# Linking to newly created Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel template with VBA code to perform a SaveCopyAs and to send email.

Users input information and SaveCopyAs creates a new file, with a generalized name based on a cell value, in a folder location specified in the code. They then hit a button that auto populates an email to the whole group.

The email recipient can only open the template not the new file.

How can I link to the file in the new location?

```vb
Private Sub cmdNot_Click()

    If Application.UserName = "Thai Nguyen" Then

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim mSubject As String
        Dim signature As String
        Dim fname As String
        Dim mBody As String
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim mailTo As String

        Set ws = Sheets("MRO")
        fname = ws.Range("B4")
        mSubject = "MRO Template" & " - For - " & Range("C6").Value

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        mBody = "\\Obmfg01\bms\000-Draft\Kaizen Training\Material Request\Manufacturing Change Order.xlsm"
        mBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
            "Dear Team,<br><br>" & _
            "Please open the file from below link and put your signature on the respective cell after you completed your task.<br><B>" & _
            ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
            "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
            "<A HREF=""file://" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
            """>Link to Workbook</A>" & _
            "<br><br>Best Regards," & _
            "<br><br></front>"

            With OutMail
                .display
            End With
            signature = OutMail.body
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With

            With OutMail
                '.To = "email"
                .To = "materials@VMAG.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = mSubject
                '.body = "Dear Team," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please open the file from below link and put your signature on the respective cell and save the sheet"
                '.htmlbody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .htmlbody = mBody
                '.Attachments.Add fileName
                .display
            End With
            'ws.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri,italic""&11& " & ws.Range("A1")
            ws.Protect ("MRO")
            Path = "\\000-Draft\Kaizen Training\Material Request\New\"
            fileName = Range("C6").Value
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=Path & fileName & ".xlsm"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing

            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With

        Else
            MsgBox "You are not authorised to send MRO form, please check with Template owner", vbInformation
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry 0m3r, i don't remember i un-accepted your answer? that is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You will need to `SaveCopyAs` before you link it to the email*

*Example*

```
    Dim path As String
    path = "\\000-Draft\Kaizen Training\Material Request\New\"
    fileName = ws.Range("C6").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=path & fileName & ".xlsm"

    mBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
        "Dear Team,<br><br>" & _
        "Please open the file from below link and put your signature on the respective cell after you completed your task.<br><B>" & _
        fileName & ".xlsm" & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
        "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
        "<A HREF=""file://" & path & fileName & ".xlsm" & _
        """>Link to Workbook</A>" & _
        "<br><br>Best Regards," & _
        "<br><br></front>"
```

---

> ```
>        "<A HREF=""file://" & path & fileName & ".xlsm" & _
>         """>Link to Workbook</A>" & _
> ```